# Rails after_remove not getting triggered with destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have venues and venue_managers, with a HABTM relationship, and I am rolling my own counter cache via after_add and after_remove callbacks. Those callbacks on the venue_managers are getting added to the venue model via a mixin. I am using am mixin because there are other models that need this same logic.

If there are 2 venue_managers and I re-assign venue_managers to just have 1, with venue.venue_managers = a_user, then the after_remove callback gets triggered and all is well. If I have 2 venue_managers and I destroy the last one with venue.venue_managers.last.destroy, the after_remove callback is NOT triggered and the counter cache does not update, which is my problem.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HABTMCounterCache

  has_and_belongs_to_many :venue_managers, :class_name => 'User', :join_table => :venues_venue_managers
end

module HABTMCounterCache
  extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def count_cache_associations
      klass = self.name.downcase
      self.send("after_add_for_#{klass}_managers") << lambda do |obj, manager|
        obj.update_counter_cache(manager)
      end

      self.send("after_remove_for_#{klass}_managers") << lambda do |obj, manager|
        obj.update_counter_cache(manager)
      end
    end
  end

  def update_counter_cache(noop)
    klass = self.class.name.downcase
    self.assign_attributes(:"#{klass}_managers_count" => self.send("#{klass}_managers").count)
  end
end
```